# Sending touch commands to an Android Device

Tags: android, touch, adb, simulate

I'm trying to get my computer (Mac/Linux) to send touch commands to my Nexus 7 tablet via ADB. I've found that I can successfully send touch events via "adb shell input tap x y", but the noticable delay is inhibiting what I can do. I would need to be able to send several per second, but this method sends at about 1 per second. I'm hoping to in the end control the inputs via a python script on the host pc if that's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)?

Or if you are looking for an automation test framework, you could try [robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

Comment: yes yes, I do believe you are right. I had been looking up Monkey which seemed to state I needed to run it on the device. I've got touch working with perfecting time now! Thanks